# cURL throws an exception at Facebook API SDK

Tags: facebook, apache, curl, wamp

I'm trying to post an image as the user from my Facebook application.
Currently, this feature is still under development, and when I'm trying to test it using `WAMP server` on `localhost`, one of the `cURL` functions in the `Facebook API SDK` class, throws an exception error:

> {"error_code":60,"error":{"message":"SSL certificate problem, verify
>   that the CA cert is OK. Details:\nerror:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify
>   failed","type":"CurlException"}}null0.90752005577087
>   145684992172054|e259ec293812a5276a61d3181c395077

I have checked, and I have the correct settings at `php.ini` both at the `Apache` and `PHP` directories.

I tried to run this Both on `Easy PHP` with `PHP 5.4` and on `WAMP` with `PHP 5.3`. (cURL extension enabled).

I have `open SSL` installed on both of the local servers.

I understand that you can solve this by changing the configuration of the `CURL_opt`, but modifying a Facebook base class, and compromising the security of my application (middle man attack), is really a last resort for me.

Thanks in advance for any help!.

My code:

```
test.php:
<?php
session_start();

require 'FB_auth.php';
require 'includes.php';
require 'functions_fb.php';

    $start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime())); 

    //echo json_encode(photoToFacebook(299, 402, 134));
    // echo json_encode(photoToFacebook(724, 402, 165));

    // postToFacebook($db, 402, 134);

    $end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime())); 
    $duration = ($end-$start);

    echo $duration;
    echo "<br/>" . $facebook->getAccessToken();

?>

functions_fb.php

<?php

function photoToFacebook($hr_id, $user_id, $job_id){


        global $db, $FEED_PATH, $JOB_IMAGES_FOLDER , $facebook;
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
        $JOB_IMAGES_FOLDER = "images/job_images/";



        $company = $db->getCompany($hr_id);

        // perapre the job photo.
        $photo = $db->getJobPhoto($job_id);
        if (empty($photo)){
            $photo = $db->getLogo($hr_id);
        }
        else{
            $photo = $JOB_IMAGES_FOLDER . $photo;
        }

        try{
            // At the time of writing it is necessary to enable upload support in the Facebook SDK, you do this with the line:
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

            // Get album id if exists.
            $album_uid = $db->getAlbumId($user_id);
            $fb_user_id = $db->getFBUserId($user_id);
            if (empty($album_uid)){

                // Create an album
                $album_details = array(
                        'message'=> 'Check out my company\'s job opportunities',
                        'name'=> "Job opportunities at {$company}"
                );


                $create_album = $facebook->api("/{$fb_user_id}/albums", 'post', $album_details);
                echo json_encode($create_album);

                $album_uid = $create_album["id"];
                $db->saveAlbumId($user_id, $create_album["id"]);
            }
            $job_title = $db->getJobTitle($job_id);

            $link = Bitly::make_bitly_url($FEED_PATH . "show_job.php?jid={$job_id}&th_uid={$user_id}&tp=1&pc=1", BITLY_APP_USERNAME,BITLY_APP_KEY,'json');
            $photo_details = array(
                'message'=> $job_title . "!\n" . $company . " is looking for you.\nOpen the link for details and apply.\n" . $link
            );

            $path .= $photo;
            $photo_details['image'] = '@' . $path; //realpath($file);

            // echo $album_uid;

            $upload_photo = $facebook->api("{$fb_user_id}/photos", 'post', $photo_details);

            // $db->updateAutoPostActivity($user_id, $job_id,1, json_encode($upload_photo));
            // $db->updateAutoPostJob($job_id, $user_id);

            return $upload_photo;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo "error:" . json_encode($e->getResult());
            // $db->updateAutoPostActivity($user_id, $job_id,1, json_encode($e->getResult()));
            // AtavMail::SendRichedMail(null , "", "Error on auto process - posting photo to FB", "Where - Job Id: {$job_id} , User Id: {$user_id}", json_encode($e->getResult()));
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the following line into the base_facebook.php file:

```
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
     //
     //
     //
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  );
```

Please notice that this is an development - environment solution only, and using this on your actual application can cause a security risk.

Please take the time to review the fullp proper solution on this link:
http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 1):

Setting SSL verification to false defeats the purpose of SSL.
A proper solution is to set the CA certs for CURL.

Solution 1 (Changes to PHP.ini):

1. Download CA bundle (cacert.pem) from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Place it on your local system (for eg: C:\xampp\cacert.pem)
3. Open your php.ini
4. Set the curl.ca_info options to point to the location of the cacert.pem

   ```
   Example: curl.ca_info="C:\xampp\cacert.pem"
   ```
5. Restart Apache

Solution 2 (Set options before each CURL call)

1. Download CA bundle (cacert.pem) from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Place it on your local system (for eg: C:\xampp\cacert.pem)
3. Write the following code:

   ```
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "pathto\cacert.pem");
   ```

Source: http://tumblr.wehavefaces.net/post/52114563111/environment-windows-xampp-curl-library